# Weighted conditional sum with dplyr

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

Thank you in advance!

I have a dataframe with patients (example below) that are obese or not. I have characteristics as Col I, J, K. This is weighted data so the weight is the number of people this patient represents. I need the last column percent obese with the same IJK.

If you also have any suggested resources for DPLYR with a lot of examples I'd appreciate it! I've done the datacamp course and looked through some additional resources as well, but looking for more.

[image: Sample dataframe]

What I've attempted, but has not worked...

```
 df <-
  df %>%
  group_by(col I, col J, col K) %>%
  mutate(weighted_total_with_same_IJK=sum(weight))

 df <-
  df %>%
  group_by(col I, col J, col K, col H) %>%
  mutate(percent_obese_with_the_same_IJK=sum(weight)/weighted_total_with_same_IJK)
```

Comment: Please show a small reproduicble example with dput

Comment: Thank you I will certainly include a small reproducible example in my next post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
df <-
  df %>%
  group_by(col I, col J, col K, col H) %>%
  mutate(percent_obese_with_the_same_IJK = if_else(col H == "obese", weight/sum(weight), "NA_real_"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked wonderfully! I wasn't sure how to add if/else to mutate and this illustrated it wonderfully!